# Visualize Data with a Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My Bar Chart look like this.

[image]

I want to configure xAxis( the year in the bottom) like this.
I am getting a duplicate year.How can I remove duplicate year?

[image]

here is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .bar {
        fill: orange;
    }

    .bar:hover {
        fill: orangered ;
    }

    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }

    .d3-tip {
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 12px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    .d3-tip:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        content: "\25BC";
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style northward tooltips differently */
    .d3-tip.n:after {
        margin: -1px 0 0 0;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatPercent = d3.format("0");

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(formatPercent);

    var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
            return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d[1] + "</span>";
        })

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    var jonData = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';
    d3.json(jonData, function(error, data) {
        if(error){
            return console.warn(error);
        }
//        console.log(data.data);

        data = data.data;
        data.map(function(d)
        {
            var date = new Date(d[0]);

            console.log(date.getFullYear());
        });
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Gross Domestic Product, USA");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[1]); })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

    });

</script>
```

I am following this link [Using d3-tip to add tooltips to a d3 bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're using an ordinal scale. You can use an ordinal scale (as you can see, the bars are showing up), but you'll have to create an *ad hoc* code to eliminate the ticks.

The "correct" approach is using a time scale, since your data is time related:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
```

However, you'll have to parse the dates:

```
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d[0] = timeFormat.parse(d[0]);
});
```

And also change the x domain:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d[0]
}));
```

Here is your code with that changes, using `ticks(10)` in the axis generator:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format("0");

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(15);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")

var jonData = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';
d3.json(jonData, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    return console.warn(error);
  }

  data = data.data;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d[0] = timeFormat.parse(d[0]);
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d[0]
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Gross Domestic Product, USA");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("width", width / data.length)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d[1]);
    })
    
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```